# How to Connect to Dockerized MySQL Database running on EC2 from Flask Web App

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to connect to a MySQL Database that is dockerized and stored in EC2 from a Flask Application. In order to get to the database manually, you have to ssh in with a pem file and then exec into the docker image to get to the database. How would I go about connecting to this from the application itself. I have tried using both sql alchemy or mysql but if I try and use the ip address to the ec2 instance it just times out. My guess is I need to do something with a Dockerfile within the Flask app maybe? I am fairly new to Flask and Docker so I am not sure what the best course of action is and could not find a lot of information online.

Comment: Can you please specify more info about the Docker container? Did you expose the 3306 port?

Comment: 3306 is not exposed. I believe 3000 is and that is where the actual node backend for the application is

Comment: actually, upon running docker-compose, 3306 is exposed as well. I did not write the backend or any of the docker files :p

Comment: Do you need to connect to the DB from the same server or from some remote?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question so I can give a little more insight into what I am doing to hopefully answer your question. The backend and the database for an application are being dockerized and hosted on ec2. I am writing an admin panel to do some data analytics on the information in the database. This is being done in Flask hence why I need the Flask application to access the database and pull down useful analytics. I was able to test this with a local version of the database stood up in docker-compose and it worked fine but I am unsure how to do it otherwise

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need to set up networking between containers or expose the port to the server and use the server's ports.

Comment: What's the OS on the server? Does it have SE Linux?

Comment: It is ubuntu...here is what it says about the ports for mysql when I run "docker container ls"

3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp

Comment: I guess the port is not properly exposed. Do you use Dockerfile or compose?

Answer (score 1):

In short, if you are able to connect to the MySQL server with one of MySQL client tools, then you'll be able to connect to it with Flask.

The process is not that simple, I can't give you commands to execute without any additional info, but overall logic is the following.

- MySQL has a server inside the docker container working on 3306 port. First, that port should be exposed to the server and probably bind to the server's 3306 port, this may be done on the `docker run` command.
  You need to run something like `docker run -p 3306:3306`. See more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)
- Second, if you want to connect to the instance from remote, you need to make sure the port is accessible from wherever you want, docker will automatically add an `iptable` record for you, but make sure if there is not a firewall blocking the port.

Given you are receiving a time-out, most probably the issue is that Flask is not able to connect through that port.